# How to get today's date in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to get today's date in format of `yyyyMMdd` in groovy language.

I have tried to do this:

```
String oldDate = '20150702'
Date date = Date.parse( 'yyyyMMdd', oldDate )
String currentDate = date.format( 'yyyyMMdd' )
```

Output: 20150702

I am trying to get today's date however.

Comment: you are working always with the old data, you should have an object containing today's value somewhere. you need this:  Date today = new Date()

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Then use:

```
new Date().format( 'yyyyMMdd' )
```

Comment: This produces warning:
warning  Do not use java.util.Date. Prefer the classes in the java.time.* packages.  NoJavaUtilDate

Comment: @sumid, which version of groovy are you using?

Comment: ```$ npm-groovy-lint --version  
npm-groovy-lint version 3.3.2  
  
Embeds:  
- CodeNarc version 1.5  
- Groovy version 3.0.2 (superlite)
```
  
I found article [Still using java.util.Date? Don’t!](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/) explaining the warning. But I assume the solution proposed is Java specific and I couldn't make it work in Groovy.

Comment: @sumid, no it's definitely not java specific.

Comment: I tried to use:
```String dateString = java.time.LocalDateTime.now().format(java.time.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'))```  
  
I got exception either: 
```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DateTimeFormatter for class: Script3```  
  
or:
```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: java for class: Script3```  
  
So what would be the correct code for LocalDateTime with a format?

Answer (score 8):

The answer of @Opal did not work for me:
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.format() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [yyyy-MM-dd]`

Here is a solution that worked for me:

`new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())`

(edit: removed extra parenth at the end of snippet)